# Fast uniform sampling of walks from directed graph

Tags: sampling, graph-theory, random-walk

Given a directed graph $G=(V, E)$ my goal is to sample a set of walks $W\subset\mathcal{W}$ where $\mathcal{W}$ is the set of all walks in $G$. I want each walk to be sampled with the uniform probability $\frac{1}{|\mathcal{W}|}$.

As a variation, I want to modify the problem to sample walks that have a given length $k$.

So far I tried the following procedure for sampling a walk of length $k$. I perform a random walk starting from a uniform chosen edge and then I continue by choosing in each step one of the neighbors with probability $1/\Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the maximum degree in $G$ or I stop at the current vertex $v$ with probability $1-(\delta(v)/\Delta)$ where $\delta(v)$ is the number of outgoing edges. If I stop, need to start again.
The probability of each path of length $k$ is $(1/\Delta)^k$.

However, the method tends to be far too slow even small $k>3$.

Is there a fast way to sample the walks? An approximate way of almost-uniform would be ok too.

Comment: Is the slowness issue related to how you've implemented the graph?

Comment: Do you need to sample the paths themselves, or just the final nodes?

Comment: @Aruralreader, I believe the slowness is related to the fact that if we have vertices with small outdegree the probability of finding a walk of length $k$ gets too low. Therefore, too many restarts lead to long a running time.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, I need the complete walk.

Comment: You could just _not_ stop at the current vertex. It amounts. to doing unnecessary rejection sampling at that vertex.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, so you mean I just take the next neighbor with a probability of $1/\delta(v)$. It would definitely speed up the process, but it would not lead to a uniform sampler, or?

Comment: You claim that staying at the same node doesn't count as part of the path. (That is, you don't have self-loops.) In that case, it's provably equivalent to your method, but faster.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy, during the process I only either go to a new vertex or I restart the complete process. Therefore, if I cannot go to a new vertex, I start a completely new walk.

Comment: My concern is that the current approach is wasteful, especially as the sparsity of the graph increases. There's a difference between "This vertex has no out-edges" (in which case you _must_ restart) and "I sampled the current vertex". The latter case is where you can (often dramatically) reduce cost—just sample from the out-edges!